# Proving that a sequence converge to $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I came upon this question while working out.

A sequence $u_n$ is defined as :

$u_1 = 1$ and $u_{n+1} = \frac12(u_{n} + 2/u_{n})$.

We have to show that this converge to square root of 2

I started like this to get a telescopic sequence

$ u_{n+1} = [(u_{n} - \sqrt{2})^2 + 2\sqrt{2}u_{n}]/2u_{n}$

from that I have got,

$ u_{n+1} = \sqrt{2} + [(u_n - \sqrt{2})^2]/2u_{n} $

I can't figure out how to go forward , I think my approach is wrong , can anyone please explain a method to get the answer?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Is the sequence monotone?

Comment: yes it is sir @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Then it will be quite easy to prove it's convergent.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/82682/42969.

Comment: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338098/convergence-of-the-sequence-x-k1-frac12x-k-fracax-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction easy to see that $u_n>0$ and by AM-GM for all $n\geq1$ we obtain: $$u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(u_n+\frac{2}{u_n}\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\sqrt{u_n\cdot\frac{2}{u_n}}=\sqrt2.$$
Also, $$u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac{2-u_n^2}{2}\leq0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: You will need the fact that $$u_n\geq 0$$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner It's obvious by induction.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Just a little curious: What version of the AM-GM inequality do you use? Why not directly $(u_n+2/u_n)/2\ge\sqrt{u_n\cdot2/u_n}$?

Comment: @Chrystomath I like $x_1+x_2+...+x_n\geq n\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n},$ where $x_i\geq0.$

Comment: ok sir, so I can proceed with the Cauchy sequence theory now , is not it ? @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: No! We proved that our sequence decreases and bounded. Now, we can use Weierstrass

Comment: can you please explain sir , I'm still stuck with that , so many people have answered it in so many ways @MichaelRozenberg